# Create annotation task with annotated document

Tags: machine-learning, annotations, ibm-watson, watson-knowledge-studio

I'm new to Knowledge Studio. I created the `Entity types`, the `Relation Types`, I pre-annotated some documents which are in an annotation set and I created an `Annotation Task` to manually annotate documents. I've also trained and evaluate the model, which had very poor performance.
Now I want to try to improve the model by creating another Annotation Task and do again the annotation.
When I try to do the `Pre-annotation` I receive the following error:

> Error: Dictionary annotator process failed: The selected documents were already annotated by humans. You cannot pre-annotate the documents now, because those annotations would overwrite the existing human annotations.

The meaning of the message is straightforward, but what if I want to **do again all the process (preannotation, annotation task, train&evaluate) on the same documents**?
I think that upload again non-annotated documents is not a solution. 
I saw that I can create another `Annotation Task`, but (of course) documents are already annotated. 

**How can I start from scratch the annotation process with documents which I previously annotate?** Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no mechanism to clear all the annotations from the documents in Knowledge Studio. If you want to try again from scratch, how about exporting and uploading the documents into a new workspace? You can upload the documents without annotations by unchecking the checkbox of `Upload corpus documents and include ground truth (upload the original workspace's type system first)` in Upload Document Sets dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your reply coy. It seems strange to me that I have to create a new workspace each time I have to train/test the model. I tried to do what you suggest, but in The _Upload Document Sets_ dialog from the `Documents` Assets doesn't appear.

Comment: The idea of uploading documents without annotations into new workspace is just workaround since there is no way to clear all annotations from the documents. As for Upload Document Sets dialog, the following link would be helpful.
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson-knowledge-studio/exportimport.html#exportimport